# mongodb aggregation, use $sum 2 individual fields and group

Tags: mongodb

As I am new to mongo, I have a slight problem getting something done the way I need it.

I am trying to group the collection by "token_address", count the occurencies of that as totalTransfers and also for each token_address sum the values of the "decimal" property.

The desired outlook would look like this

```json
{
    "token_address" : "0x2a746fb4d7338e4677c102f0ce46dae3971de1cc",
    "totalTransfers" : 4.0,   //occurencies per token_address in collection
    "decimal" :132.423        //the $sum of each decimal per token_address
}
```

This is how the documents look

```json
{
    "_id" : "BrBr1vuhNRmmaZliYopQocD2",
    "from_address" : "0x7ed77e237fa0a87fc12afb92d2999e6f90e1d43b",
    "log_index" : 442,
    "to_address" : "0x31d5e41636c2331d8be9ea9c4393a0ff4e597b6c",
    "transaction_hash" : "0x1a80b66839b021ef9c1a902f19d28b77d8e688b2e3ebb9bfc185443ae1830403",
    "_created_at" : ISODate("2022-03-21T14:09:49.894Z"),
    "_updated_at" : ISODate("2022-03-21T14:09:49.894Z"),
    "block_hash" : "0x80dfe8642f998ce7fb3e692ab574d9786efdd81ba6aeace060ae9cc919a8acbf",
    "block_number" : 14209975,
    "block_timestamp" : ISODate("2022-02-15T09:47:30.000Z"),
    "confirmed" : true,
    "decimal" : NumberDecimal("0.1206"),
    "historical" : true,
    "token_address" : "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
    "transaction_index" : 278,
    "value" : "120600000000000000"
}
```

This is my aggregation which gives which results in the last output

```js
db.EthTokenTransfers.aggregate([
    {  $project: {
            token_address : 1 // Inclusion mode
         }},
      { $group : { _id : '$token_address', totalTransfers : { $sum : 1 }, decimal: {$sum:"$decimal"}
     
      } }
    ])
```

```json
{
    "_id" : "0x2a746fb4d7338e4677c102f0ce46dae3971de1cc",
    "totalTransfers" : 4.0,
    "decimal" : 0
}
```

Can some one point me towards the correct way of doing this? I been trying for over an hour for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your are removing fields in the `$project` stage.

Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n7DGxf_4TWj) only with the first stage where the output is only the field `token_address`.

So to the next aggregation stage this is the income data, only the `token_address`. And that's why `totalTransfers`is correct (you group by the existing `token_address` field and `$sum` one for each one) but `decimal` is always 0, because the field does not exists.

One solution can be add `decimal` into `$project` like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kk-vw--8O43)